# Unexpected issue in Css3 html5 Div alignement when applying border-left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to produce a report using html5 and css3  but I got an unexpected behavior. what I need is to understand Why  div are not aligned

**CSS3**

```
.lineDiv{ border-left: 5px solid #FF0000; background:whitesmoke;height:30px; margin-top: 10px; }
/* */
.titleDiv {border-bottom:5px solid OrangeRed;border-top: 4px solid #FFFFFF; text-align: center;  ;background:gainsboro;height: 50px;  font-size: 18px;color:#2F4F4F ; font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px white;}

.mainDiv{
   margin: auto;height: 600px;width: 600px; border: 1px solid gray; }
.bodyDiv
{
  margin: 10%;
   align-content: center;

}
.labelP
{ float: left; margin-top: 7px;width: 80px;  border-right: 1px solid white;vertical-align: middle;
   text-align:left;  font-size: 15px;color:#2F4F4F ; font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
}
.labelTxt
{display: inline-block; ; margin-top: 7px;width: 80px;  vertical-align: middle;width:auto;
   text-align:left;  font-size: 15px;color:#2F4F4F ; font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif; text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
}


.sectionDiv {border-right:5px solid OrangeRed;border-left:5px solid OrangeRed; text-align: center;  ;background:gainsboro;height: 24px;  font-size: 16px;color:#2F4F4F ; font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px white; margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

**HTML5**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Job Alert</title>
</head>

  <body>
    <!-- Start your code here -->
    <div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="titleDiv"><p>Unexpected result  detected</p></div>
       <!-- Body Div-->

     <div class="bodyDiv">       
       <div class="sectionDiv">Job Information</div>

       <div class="lineDiv"><span class="labelP">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span class="labelTxt">&nbsp;GUI TEST  </span><div> 

         <div class="lineDiv"><span class="labelP">JID&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span class="labelTxt">12345 </span><div>
            <div class="lineDiv"><span class="labelP">JID&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span class="labelTxt">12345 </span><div>


    </div>
    </div>



</div></div></div></div></div></div></body>
```

**Result**
 following is the permanent link  http://liveweave.com/z25PTh on liveweave

SO why div are not aligned? 
Can anyone explain or optimize this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not closed your div blocks, close div blocks...

```
<div class="lineDiv"><span class="labelP">Name&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span class="labelTxt">&nbsp;GUI TEST  </span>**<div> <-------   </div>**

<div class="lineDiv"><span class="labelP">JID&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><span class="labelTxt">12345 </span>**<div> <-------   </div>**
```

Comment: There are also way to many </div> parts at the end of the page.